# How to query data without create model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sometimes, I need to query lots of data in DB for data processing.

For example, I have a table: Activity, I want to find all the users which create activity in the last month,

I am only concerned about the data arrays, and I don't want to create a lot of Activity models,

Is there any way I can do it?

like this code:

```
Activity.where('created_at > ?', Time.now - 1.month).get_data(:user_id, :created_at)
=> [[1, 2012-02-01] .... ]
```

Comment: I'm confused on your wording. "{You} don't want to create Activity models" "I only concern about the data arrays" ? Not sure I understand. Why would you be creating models by doing a query?

Comment: Are you saying you want to query your DB with rails-like conditions but don't want to create all those rails models?

Comment: @Bornfree Yes. I think it is a very common scenario.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
sql = "SELECT * from activities limit 10"
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
result.to_a
```

I'm not sure about sql query but I think you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Activity.where(['activities.user_id = ? 
                 AND activities.created_at BETWEEN ? 
                 AND ?', users, 1.month.ago, Time.zone.now])
```

This will return all of the activities that have been created over the past month for a set of users.  The only potential issue with this query is with extremely large datasets.  You might want to use a named_scope to narrow down the activities before you run this query so that it doesn't search over every activity in the db.